# MessageBox 'Could not load TalkAPI library' pops up after defining an Excel Application in C# .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com, office-interop

I would like to load data into an Excel file via the Com Interface to Excel in C#. Before this I define an Excel Application:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelapplication = new Application();

...
```

After the defintion of the application a MessageBox pops up which shows the following text: 'Could not load TalkAPI library'.

Does anybody know what this is about? I could not find a thing online.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Comment: First, I recommend you fully qualify `Application`. It won't necessarily be clear to C# that you mean Excel, and not itself. In what application window is this message displaying? Is it looking for something in your .NET code, or in Excel? It's possible that the Excel installation on the machine where this is running has an add-in that's looking for this. Do you see the problem when you start Excel on the same machine as a user?

Comment: The message is displayed  directly after defining the application as a Message coming from Excel. What do you mean with 'qualifiying' in this context? I am not shure about the add-in. Where can I see this? I don't see this problem on the same machine as a user.

Comment: Fully qualify: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelapplication = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();`

Comment: If you google "TalkAPI" there are "hits". No idea which one this might be. But something is certainly referencing it...

Comment: I could not find a solution yet. Maybe I have to use an older Interop dll?! I am using Excel 2010

Comment: Have you tried on a different machine with a different user profile? This is certainly NOTHING that's part of Excel. It's third-party, whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could find the cause for the issue: As Cindy Meister stated, it is a third-party problem. The problem is more precise the COM Add-in 'OfficeLink' which has to be deactivated in Excel for the Excel Interop to work correct without the MessageBox popping up. Probably, it is an issue coming from one of the dlls of the Add-in (probably TalkApiNET.dll).

However, it means the Excel Interop is not usable for proper UX when this Add-In is activated in the current version.